# Remove object from array when condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'John'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Harry'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Peter'}
]
```

I want to remove object containing 'John' from the array only if 'Harry' is in the array.

I need to support IE11 and do not want to use polyfills. Thanks

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: See Array.prototype.some() to determine if array contains 'Harry'. If it does, use Array.prototype.filter() to keep all objects except the one containing 'John'. Both Array methods are IE 11 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

```
let response = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Harry'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Peter'
}]

if (response.filter(object => object.name === 'Harry').length > 0) {
  response = response.filter(object => object.name !== 'John')
}

console.log(response)
```